# Changing a TD attribute with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

The title may be confusing because I'm not sure what my 'attribute' is, so I'll show the line of code that I want to change.

```
echo "<td sorttable_customkey = $value>";
```

The 'sorttable_customkey' is needed for a library that helps me to sort tables.

What I want to do is change 'value' in my Jquery. I know what the new value is and I have my 'td' element in a variable. What I don't know, is how I find the 'sorttable_customkey = 1' inside that element and replace the 1 with a 2 (for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st in this php if $value is php varibale your code should be

```
echo "<td sorttable_customkey = '".$value."'>";
```

2nd: to change attr in jquery

```
$('td[sorttable_customkey]').attr('sorttable_customkey' , '2');
```

3rd: if you want to get the attr value

```
 var getAttr = $('td[sorttable_customkey]').attr('sorttable_customkey');
```

before everything check you include jquery

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Why do I need to change to '".$value."'>" ? It seems to be working fine my way, is there something wrong with the way I'm doing it?

Comment: @Farflame it something called [concatenate in php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) .. may it help

Comment: But is there something wrong with my method, since it works fine and gives the same result? Is concatenation more stable or something?

Comment: @Farflame No if its works in your way its Ok .. but everything has basics so I should let you know what the basic is  may you need it later :)

Comment: Thanks. I agree that it's better to do things correctly from the beginning so I'll do it this way from now on.

Thanks, have ticked your answer :)